# eBay API change currency of returned price

Tags: ebay-api

Is there a way to get an item in another currency using the eBay API?

Comment: Why do you want another currency, I think the currency depends on the eBay-site where you are listing your items. For example German eBay site uses EUR, US-site uses US-Dollar.

Comment: Im not sure if I did this right, but I changed the item-id to the itemId of an item thats put up on the de-market..but it still returns USD in the api..
I need to change the currency since my client dont want to display the price in USD..but in eur

Comment: Just do a get item call against a different country, example 3 for UK, you would retreive the same item's price in Euros

Answer (score 4):

Very simple. All you have to do is change the site ID parameter. Since you didn't specify a language, I'm going to assume you're doing this HTTP-GET and just parsing the XML. The same principles will apply regardless of how you do it, programatically or not.

For a URL:

"http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping"

- ?callname=GetSingleItem
- &responseencoding=XML
- &appid=[APPID]
- &siteid=2 <------------This, for example, is Canada's siteid. 0 is US. This will change the currency returned under < ConvertedCurrentPrice>
- &version=839
- &ItemID=181195344321

Put it all together and you get this copy/paste-friendly "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=XML&appid=[APPID]&siteid=2&version=839&ItemID=181195344321"

Make sure to use your app ID as the parameter.

Comment: This applies only for currencies supported by ebay SiteCodeTypes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this call for currency change:
Currency type can be changed in Ebay while listing an item using Add Item call in Ebay's trading API.
http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/extra/additms.rqst.additmrqstcntnr.itm.crrncy.html

Thanks
 CedCommerce

Answer (score 0):

You can and it's actually very simple. You can use the Shopping API GetSingleItem.
Depending on what currency you are interested in, all you have to do is change the SiteID on which you are making the call. For example, if you want to get the price in EUR, you can set the SiteID to 3(UK), or 77(Germany). You will also have to set the IncludeSelector to "Details". This way, you will get a response that will contain the following fields.

```
<ConvertedCurrentPrice currencyID="GBP">68.55</ConvertedCurrentPrice>
<CurrentPrice currencyID="USD">92.9</CurrentPrice>
```

where the CurrentPrice is the original price of the listing, on the ebay site the listing was made, and the ConvertedCurrentPrice is the price of the listing on the site that corresponds to the SiteID you supplied.
You can see a full list of SiteIDs with the currencies they are using [here](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/sitecodetype.html)